# Template and function Overloading

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

To study the Overloading of Function Templates, I have wrote two functions:

```
template <typename T>
void pe16_61_compare(const T&, const T&) {
    cout <<"template pe16_61_compare(T, T) called" << endl;
}

// plain functions to handle C-style character strings
void pe16_61_compare(const char*, const char*) {
    cout <<"normal func pe16_61_compare(...) called" << endl;;
}
```

and then I have defined some variables and called the function: pe16_61_compare

```
const char const_arr1[] = "world", const_arr2[] = "hi";
char ch_arr1[] = "world";
// first call
pe16_61_compare(ch_arr1, const_arr1);
// second call
pe16_61_compare(const_arr1, const_arr2);
```

the output result is:

```
template pe16_61_compare(T, T) called
normal func pe16_61_compare(...) called
```

What confuse me is that the first call invoke the template function. For me, for the first call, both two pe16_61_compare function are viable functions and the have the same rank of conversion (non-const to const and array to pointer), and it is said in this case, the template function should be removed from the set of viable functions.

Could any one tell me why?
Thank you for considering my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first call, `T =  char[6]` is a better match than the conversion to `char const *`, so the template wins.

For the second call, no single template parameter can work for arrays, so the non-template overload is the only matching one.

If you say,

```
pe16_61_compare(static_cast<char const *>(const_arr_1),
                static_cast<char const *>(const_arr_2));
```

then both the template instance and the ordinary function are viable and have the same signature, but as a tie breaker the non-template function wins (i.e. this isn't ambiguous).

Comment: Thanks Kerrek :) I think that your answer is right but could you please tell me how I can verify that T = char[6] for the first call?

Comment: @Tianyi: Throw some traits at it: `std::is_array`, `std::extent`, `std::remove_extent`, etc. And/or run the type through your favourite demangler.

Comment: For the conversion of array to pointer, it seems that I have made a mistake, it is said in <C++ Primer> that "If the template parameter is not a reference type, then the normal pointer conversion will be applied to arguments of array or function type." So I think that there will not be the conversion of array to pointer for the template function...

Comment: @Tianyi: If you omitted the second overload entirely, both calls should still work and use the template.

Comment: @Kerrke SB: I have just comments the second function and in eclipse CDT, I got this error msg: "no matching function for call to ‘pe16_61_compare(const char [6], const char [3])".

Comment: @Tianyi: Ah, interesting. Looks like you'll have to cast to a pointer manually to make that work. I'll edit the answer then!

Comment: @Tianyi: This situation is similar to if you had `int a; unsigned int b; foo(a, b);`: Even though conversions exist, the template argument deduction is ambiguous. To make it work, you need to convert to a common type manually. The same applies to the conversion `char const [N]` to `char const *` that we have here.

Comment: @Kerrke SB: Thanks for your comment, I will think about it :)